# pytest command used in gitlab CICD pipeline does not automatically pick test_* script and throws error "CoverageWarning: No data was collected."

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, code-coverage, cicd

I have "src/bin" folder to store the code and "tests" folder to store my test scripts. I am using the below pytest command in my pipeline

```
pytest /builds/cdf/Platform/onprem-core-functions/test/ --cov=src --cov-report xml:coverage/cov.xml --cov-branch
```

but it fails with the below error.

```
CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

Also please note that if I keep my test script in the home directory instead of "test" folder, then the below pytest command runs successfully.

```
pytest --cov=src --cov-report xml:coverage/cov.xml --cov-branch
```

However, in order to keep all my test scripts outside my application code, I intend to move them into a separate "test" folder instead of cluttering the home directory. Can you please advise where am i going wrong.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."

Comment: Did you install pytest-cov?

Comment: Yes I have installed pytest-cov